# How to get the children of a realtime database in kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

[This the Realtime Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIUcP.png)

Here I want to retrieve whether the user is a recruiter or a student in Kotlin as a string.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, the Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start) or one of the many tutorials out there are probably the best places to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can create a query to get certain users (recruiters or students) without knowing the type of the user beforehand. If you need to get all recruiters or all students from the database, then you should consider using a database schema that allows that. So please check the following approach:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- users
       |
       --- w73...C32
       |    |
       |    --- password: "123456"
       |    |
       |    --- email: "test2@gmail.com"
       |    |
       |    --- type: "recruiter" 
       |
       --- aG4...383
            |
            --- password: "123456"
            |
            --- email: "test@gmail.com"
            |
            --- type: "student"
```

If want to get, for example, all recruiters from the `users` node, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("users");
Query queryRecruiters = usersRef.orderByChild("type").equalTo("recruiter");
queryRecruiters.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String email = ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", email);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
test2@gmail.com
```

On the other hand, if you know the email address and you want to check the type of the user (recruiter/student), then please use the following lines of code:

```
Query queryByEmail = usersRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo("test2@gmail.com");
queryByEmail.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                String type = ds.child("type").getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("TAG", type);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
recruiter
```

---

Please note that I have added all node names and fields [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did exactly the same as you approached the problem. I didn't know that we have to know the user id first then we can fetch all the other details.